# Vuejs router and beforeEach hook

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I’ve encountered an issue with beforeEach hook of vue-router : I checked the authentification of the user with a router.beforeEach hook in my main.js like this :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Login' && to.name !== 'PasswordReset' && to.name !== 'ForgetPass' && to.name !== 'SsoLogin') {
    Auth.isLogged()
      .then(() => {
        next();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        next(`/login?redirectUrl=${to.fullPath}`);
      });
  }
  next();
});
```

The problem is that the webpage is displayed for 1 seconde before the redirection takes place.
I’ve tried to put the code above before the Vue.use(Router) like I saw on Internet but it didn’t fixed anything.
I can fix it by using beforeEnter() on each route but I want to use a global solution instead of having to multiply code on each route.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(...) {
    Auth.isLogged().then().catch();
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

You need to add else, since Auth.isLogged() is asynchronous. If you don't add else, the last next() will always been executed. So, you will see the page first`(last next() been executed)`, and then page redirect `(code in then() or catch() block been executed)`.